# Surds question grade 9

Tags: exponentiation, radicals, fractions

I am a student and I need help answering this question.

Simplify:

$\frac{6}{\sqrt{28}}$-$\frac{9}{\sqrt{63}}$

What I did:

$\frac{6}{\sqrt{28}}$- $\frac{9}{\sqrt{63}}$

=$\frac{6}{\sqrt{7×4}}$ - $\frac{9}{\sqrt{7×4}}$

= $\frac{6}{2\sqrt{7}}$ - $\frac{9}{3\sqrt{7}} $

$\frac{6}{2\sqrt{7}}$ × $\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{2\sqrt{7}}$ = $\frac{12\sqrt{7}}{14}$

$\frac{9}{3\sqrt{7}}$ × $\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{3\sqrt{7}}$ = $\frac{27\sqrt{7}}{63}$

($\frac{12\sqrt{7}}{14}$)/2 = $\frac{6\sqrt{7}}{7}$

($\frac{27\sqrt{7}}{63}$)
/2 = $\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{7}$

$\frac{6\sqrt{7}}{7}$ - $\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{7}$

= $\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{7}$

Thankyou and help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer is $0$. You are incorrect here... $\frac{6}{2\sqrt{7}}$ × $\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{2\sqrt{7}} = \frac{12\sqrt{7}}{28}=\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{7}$

Comment: Oh I had made a silly error. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: And you are a student perhaps. _not studest :-)_

Comment: Oh I'm making too many errors today.☺

Comment: So, as I [scan your profile,](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/395614/oliviaaages) it seems you claim to be, simultaneously, a student in 8th grade, 9th grade, and 10th grade.  Ooh, and you also seem to have claimed to be at the level of 5th-6th grade.  Hmmm.  Something smells fishy here.

Comment: If you insist on repeatedly asking about surds and fractions, and or simplifying through rationalizing such, I'll have little choice than to flag your questions, and ask for a moderator to review your profile, in which you repeatedly ask similar questions, under the guise, of what I assume to be the case, a student much younger than you are.

Comment: The questions are on what grade they are usually at and in GCSE'S you get questions from all grade from grade 6 to 10

Answer (score 0):

Simply note that
$$\frac{6}{\sqrt{28}}-\frac{9}{\sqrt{63}}=\frac{6}{2\sqrt7}-\frac{9}{3\sqrt7}=\frac{3}{\sqrt7}-\frac{3}{\sqrt7}=0$$

Comment: Oh I had made a silly error. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{6}{\sqrt{28}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{7}} = \frac{9}{\sqrt{63}}$

You made some typos in your work.

Comment: Oh I had made a silly error. Thank you for helping me.